# Livewire 3 wire:navigate return blank page with text "2023"

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am developing an application with Laravel Livewire 3 and a bootstrap template
I created a layout as indicated, for now I have created two components Dashbord and Calendar
When I navigate between the two pages using wire:navigate, I receive a blank page with the text "2023". But when I refresh, the real page is displayed.
I don't know what the problem is, please help me

I would like to have a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.